# PHP using preg_replace to highlight string that is part of a word

Tags: php, arrays, regex, preg-replace, word-boundary

So I have the following code which highlights the word/s which were entered into a search bar in search results:

```
$sk = explode(" ",$searchVal); 
    foreach ($searchPostResults as $pagePosts)
        echo '<li><span class="searchResult"><a href="' 
        . get_the_permalink($pagePosts->ID) . '" title="">' . 
        preg_replace('/\b(' . implode('|', $sk) . ')\b/iu', 
                     '<strong class="searchHighlight">\0</strong>', 
                     get_the_title($pagePosts->ID)) 
         . '</a></span></li>';
```

Now it works for the most part.
Lets say I enter the search term "how to" in the search bar, the word how is highlighted.
Now if the word how is inside another word like shower, I would like to highlight how like so:

```
s<strong class="searchHighlight">how</strong>er
```

Anyone know how I might adjust the code to do this.

Cheers

Comment: @chris85 Thanks that did the trick, didn't realise \b was the boundary. Will need to keep that in mind for the future. thanks champ :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The behavior you are describing is the opposite of most peoples intentions, and probably why your regex has the `\b` in it. The `\b` is a [word boundary](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) and makes it so you can have only full word matches. Remove the `\b`s and it should work. You also won't need the capture group.

```
preg_replace('/' . implode('|', $sk) . '/iu',
```

Comment: You're going to join the new club soon there Chris ;-) well-explained answer btw.

Comment: *Wwwwwwwwwwwink!*

Comment: @Fred-ii- Thanks, it's nice in here.

Comment: Welcome Chris. You'll see what you can now do what others can't, up until they join "the 20k club", *cheers!* and congrats; you deserve it. You give good, well-explained answers and help out a lot :)